# Find the angle that a curve makes with the meridians in $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $X(\theta,\phi)=(\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin\theta\sin \phi, \cos\theta)$ be parametrization of the sphere $S^2$. Let $P$ be the plane $x=z \cot\alpha$, $0<\alpha<\pi$ and $\beta$ be the angle wich the curve $P\cap S^2$ makes with the semimeridian $\phi=\phi_0$. Compute $\cos \beta$.

This is question 2 of sec. 2.5 of DoCarmo - Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces. Which is supposed to use concepts concerning the First Fundamental Form.

I finded a parametrization of the intersection curve as follows:

if $x=z\cot\alpha$, then

$z^2\cot^{2}\alpha+y^2+z^2=1$ which implies that $y^{2}+\dfrac{z^{2}}{\sin^{2}\alpha}=1$.

So, if $y(t)=\cos t$, $z(t)=\sin\alpha\sin t$, for the condition of intersection we will have $x(t)=\cos\alpha\sin t$. So $\lambda(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ is a parametrization of the intersection. But from now on I could not do anything to solve the problem. I think I must to write $\lambda^\prime$ in terms of the basis of the tangent vector of $S^2$. But this gave me a system that I couldn't solve. Any hint?.

Remark: I know that there is some topics in this site about this question. But I couldn't understand the answers.

Comment: Can you link to the articles you mention and precise what you don't understand in order to avoid starting from scratch?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I want to calculate $\cos\beta$ by means of the first fundamental form. But for that, I must to have the intersection curve represented by means of the parametrization in order to representate its derivatives on the basis $X_{\theta}, X_{\phi}$. But I finded that curve $\lambda$ which is not related with the parametrization $X$. Can I relate $\lambda $ to $X$ or there is some easiest way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:
You should work with the parametric equations of the sphere from the beginning. We have $x=\sin\theta\cos\phi = (\cot\alpha) z = \cot\alpha\cos\theta$, so $\tan\theta\cos\phi=\cot\alpha$. Can you find the tangent vector at the point where $\phi=\phi_0$?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is constant, taking the derivative in both sides I finded out the following equation: $\theta^{\prime}=\cos\theta\sin\theta\tan\phi\phi^{\prime}$. So computing $\cos\beta$ by means of the first fundamental form I came with $\cos\beta=\dfrac{\theta^{\prime}}{\sqrt{(\theta^{\prime})^2+(\phi^{\prime})^2\sin^2\theta}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: We don't have any $t$ parametrization here. You should get an answer that depends just on $\phi_0$.